# how can I know where users come from if they are coming from another website of mine?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two websites, website A and website B, the website A is a hotsite that is linked to website B, where the sales happen.

We need to know how the user got the website A and turned into a customer in website B(it means he bought something), so we can mesure the good sources to invest.

as the developer, I have access to these two websites source-code and can implement any google-analytic tag on them.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Web browsers generally send a [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header, which contains the URL of the page which linked to the current page.

You can access this in the HTTP requests made to site B, and track sessions differently when the first page load is referred by site A. You can also access a `document.referrer` property in JavaScript, and use it to manipulate your analytics.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to implement this in Google Analytics is to configure the trackers so that they work cross-domain.

This will allow you to see all the information about where the converting visits originally came from and their path to purchase.

> If you don’t use cross-domain tracking or you have it improperly configured, you’ll end up with meaningless data that shows self-referrers in the visit reports and a lack of proper attribution towards your conversion points.  As a visitor moves from your primary domain to the other, they will start a brand new session in Google Analytics.
>
> ...
>
> If a visitor clicks an ad or performs and organic search and ends up viewing a page on the www.3rdpartycheckout.com after viewing pages on www.primarydomain.com, you lose ALL data about how that user arrived and the complete picture of what they did.  If they end up converting, you will only know that they came from www.primarydomain.com (which is not helpful at all).

- http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking/

Answer (score 0):

Have the landing page on website B look at the referrer tag and if its website A then use a separate Google Analytics instance on website B for all sessions that were sourced from website A.